# Oracle APEX - How to not escape special characters in an IG column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an IG on my APEX page and a column that contains a linebreak `<br>`. If I was using IR I could have set the property to not escape special characters but I must have an IG. Is there a workaround for an IG column not to escape special characters without having to switch to IR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to escape special characters only if you opt to *display* that column's contents (i.e. not modify it).

If that's OK with you, set column's type to **display only**. Then scroll down to its "Security" section and you'll see the "Escape special characters" property.

Comment: found it! Thanks!